# return deferred or deferred.promise()

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

The following code is absolutely okay.

```
       function wait(ms) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            setTimeout(deferred.resolve, ms);
            return deferred.promise();
        }
        wait(1500).then(function () {
            console.log("We waited 1500ms");
        });
```

If I replace `return deferred.promise()` with `return deferred` it seems to me absolutely okay,too. However *is there any difference between them or some cases which would produce some unexpected errors*? I am wondering for everyone prefers the first version.

Thank you

Comment: returning deferred would return an object with resolve/reject methods (and others no doubt) ... returning deferred.promise() should return an object that does not have those methods - true "Promise/A+" promises do NOT have the resolve/reject methods in the returned object

Comment: In some libraries deferreds and promises have different interfaces: promises are thenable, deferreds are not.